# How do I connect to the AWS IoT cloud using a GSM based device?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, stm32, gsm, aws-iot

I have GSM based device which need to send data to my AWS cloud. I'm using MQTT. How to continue further?

I downloaded embedded c SDK and I have certificates generated from AWS. Now I included all them up to my project repository and completed compiling

I'm using a SARA R4 12M GSM module and STM32L in my device

I already established an MQTT connection. Now it's sending data to the hiveMQ broker. it's working well.

Now I need to send data for the AWS cloud I have account certificates and every basic file are included to my repo.